# Export to Excel not working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I have a code that will generate an excel report.i am using ASP.NET MVC 4. I googled and found the same code everywhere still my code is not working why. My code in controller is as:

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
     string[] abc = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
     GridView gv = new GridView();
     gv.DataSource = abc;
     gv.DataBind();
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.Buffer = true;
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
     Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
     Response.Charset = "";
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
     gv.RenderControl(htw);
     Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();

     return RedirectToAction("_EligibilityCriteria");  
}
```

Just to test the export functionality I used an array `abc` this code is working in .net application but not in ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I have debugged the code but not found a problem or error in code.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line after RenderControl, what is the content of sw?

Comment: i am getting {<div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Item</th>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>AAA</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>BBB</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a way to export to excel.

```
 public void ExportIniEmployeeToExcel(EligibilityCriteriaModel AllIniEmp)
    {
        List<AllIniEmployees> emp = new List<AllIniEmployees>();            
        AllIniEmp.allSuccessEmployeeList.ForEach(x =>
            {
                AllIniEmployees allEmp = new AllIniEmployees();
                allEmp.EmployeeCode = x.EmployeeCode;
                allEmp.EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName;
                allEmp.Designation = x.Designation;
                allEmp.DeliveryTeam = x.DeliveryTeam;
                allEmp.ConfirmationDate = x.ConfirmationDate;
                emp.Add(allEmp);
            });
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = emp;
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=InitiatedEmployees.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

here i used parent class as a parameter and used linq.now its working perfectly fine.
thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just *write* the output with a `StringWriter`. After your call to `RenderControl`, write:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.ASCII);

Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
Response.End();
```

Comment: What is the problem now??

Comment: nothing happens there's no error while debugging.but the same code in asp.net C# app generates an excel.

Comment: Strange, it should work. Maybe instead of returning a RedirectToAction, you can just return some "dummy" JSON or a View.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a [`ContentResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of writing directly to the output stream.